# Limit of Identifier?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

If I have a kind called Stuff. I then try to insert an entity with a key such as this:

```
Key = ("Stuff", "A_string_key_which_say_has_1000_characters...").
```

Is there a limit on the the id length? I know the entity cant be >1mb, but does the key itself also have a limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys cannot exceed 1,500 bytes.

Regardless, I would recommend against using very long Strings in keys. Keys are used in indexes and references. Large keys mean more storage space used and more data moved around. For large apps or apps with many users it adds up.